# AWK: replace space by underscore in 2nd column

Tags: awk

I have a 2column,tab delimiterde file:

```
email@address   Name Fullname
```

(note: between `Name` and `Fullname` is a space)

---

What I would like to get is a mutt alias file:

```
alias nickname Name Fullname email@address
```

(note: No tabs here everything is a space.)

---

I fixed

```
awk -F "\t" '{ print "alias" " " $2 " " $2 " " $1 }' $FILE
```

which gives me:

> alias Name Fullname Name Fullname email@address

but I would like to get:

```
alias Name_Fullname Name Fullname email@address
```

So, how to replace all spaces in 2nd column with underscores?
Thanks

---

I tried

```
awk -F "\t" '{ print "alias" " " sub(/ /,"_",$2) " " $2 " " $1 }' $FILE
```

but that gives me the strange:

```
alias 1 Name_Fullname email@ddress
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
awk -F "\t" '{x=$2;print "alias" " " gsub(/ /,"_",x) " " $2 " " $1 }' $FILE
```

Comment: +1 - Replace all those `" "` with commas to give the same effect but look neater. The commas get replaced with `OFS` which defaults to a space. @user1427715: The reason yours didn't work and this one does is that `sub()` and `gsub` make the replacement in-place.

Comment: `awk -F "\t" '{ x=$2; gsub(/ /,"_",$2); print "alias", $2, x, $1 }' $FILE` Did it, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

What about using default input delimiters:

```
awk '{printf "alias %s %s_%s %s %s %s\n", $2, $3, $2, $3, $1}' $FILE
```

Comment: Problem is 2nd column "Name Fullname" contains sometimes 1 sometimes 2 or more spaces.